# Compute damages and savings for motor insurance claims

Tags: python, hash-map, database, pandas

I am working on some claims data, where I have features such as

[image: claims data spreadsheet]

The descriptions of the columns are: (A) the year of claim, (B) who's the insuring company (C) whether the vehicle is driven, (D) circumstance code (E) delay in raising claim (F) Vehicle age (G) Damages (H) Savings.

Damages and Savings columns are empty: I have to fill the columns damages and savings with the weights/values of each of the (A) to (F) columns. The weights of these columns are given in an another spreadsheet. The other spreadsheet has 2 sheets again (i) is damages values and (ii) is savings values.

I have created a simple dictionary comprehension code like this:

[image: Second spreadsheet image]

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path
damages = 6.5143
savings = -1.6044
year = {}
driven = {}
vehicle_age = {}
insurer = {}
code = {}
delay = {}
my_dic = pd.read_excel("values111.xlsx", index_col=None)
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
cols = list(df)
year = dict(zip(my_dic.year, my_dic.year_values))
driven = dict(zip(my_dic.driven, my_dic.driven_values))
age = dict(zip(my_dic.vehicle_age, my_dic.vehicle_age_values))
insurer = dict(zip(my_dic.insurer, my_dic.insurer_values))
code = dict(zip(my_dic.code, my_dic.code_values))
delay = dict(zip(my_dic.delay, my_dic.delay_values))
list_of_df = df.to_numpy().tolist()
#list_of_df = df.to_numpy().tolist()
for i in list_of_df:
    
    damages = 6.5143
    
    damages = damages + year[i[1]]
    damages = damages + driven[i[3]]
    damages = damages + insurer[i[2]]
    damages = damages + code[i[4]]
    damages = damages + delay[i[5]]
    
    i[7] = damages
    
    
New_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_df, columns=cols)
(New_df)
```

---

However, I wanted to check if there's a better approach/alternative than this approach. Perhaps a more comprehension-based approach where the `for` loops can be avoided?

I feel it's a little hard coded here, with a lot of indexes (column indexing) approach used.  The original dataset has many columns; giving out the indexes can be cumbersome.

The spreadsheets of values of the columns where these weights are present have separate sheets of damages and savings. Perhaps this can be included seamlessly without doing the computations two times?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your spreadsheet data as csv (comma separated values). Preferably integrated into your post.